# Почему в слайдере owl-carousel вылазит кусок другой картинки?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

При первоначальном запуске сайта, в слайдере немного показывается часть другой картинки, но когда я захожу в меню отладки и обратно, то этот глюк пропадает. Данный блок называется stucco-gal
сам сайт http://norum1991.beget.tech/
[image: h]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
  
.content {
  margin-left: 330px;
  position: relative;
}


button, a {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*section main*/


.main-section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.info {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 70;
  padding: 20px;

}

.info-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;

}
.info-text p {
   font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
.info-button {
  background-color: #b36060;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.info-button:hover {
    outline: 2px solid white !important;
    
}

.arrow {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
/*sidebar*/
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 80;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.logo {
  width: 245px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.logo span {
  position: absolute; 
  transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  background: url(../img/menu_bg.jpg);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14.2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.desc p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #aaa9a9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.menu-main {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.menu-main ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(../img/rectangle.svg) center no-repeat;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.menu-main ul li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.menu-main ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff7200;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.menu-main li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686464;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}
.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.phone {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
.contact a.request {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #c57c40;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c57c40;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.contact a.request:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*section stucco*/

.stucco-section {
  background: url(../img/lepnina-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


 .title {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
 }

 .title span {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

 .title:before, .title:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1.5px;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
  }

 .title:before {
    left: -10px;
 }


 .title:after {
    right: -10px;
 }


 .gallery-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
 }

 
 
 .stucco-gal-info {
    border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
    padding: 120px;
    z-index: 70;
    transform: translateX(-20%);
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

 .stucco-gal-info h3 {
    color: #786455;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 50px 90px;
  }
    

 .stucco-gal-info p {
    color: #979494;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans';
    margin: 0 0 60px 90px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  a.gal-btn {
    margin: 0 0 50px 90px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #8a796c;
    border: 3px solid #e2aa7b;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Lora;
    font-style: italic;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
  }


  a.gal-btn:hover {
    background: #e2aa7b;
    color: #fff;
  }

  
  .stucco-gal .owl-dots {
    margin-left: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  

  .stucco-gal .owl-dot {
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      background-color: #dcdcdc;
      border-radius: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }


  .stucco-gal .owl-dot.active {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
  }


/*Slider*/
  .container {
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .container img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

 .stucco-gal {
    width: 50%;
 }

 .img {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 100%; 
   
 }

 .pbg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat
 }

 .stucco-wrap {
  outline: 1px solid red;
 }

.owl-nav {
  display: none !important;
}

.main-section .owl-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}

.main-section .owl-dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.owl-dot.active {
  transform: scale(1.8);
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/*Popup*/
.popup{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 100;
}

.popup-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 980px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
   

.popup-form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}


.popup-img img  {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 55px;

}


.form-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}


.popup-form h3 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.popup-form input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
 

.popup-form  p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup-form input:focus, .popup-form textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #b75d5d;
}

.popup-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}


.popup h3 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.095em;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.popup sup {
  color: #b25252;
   font-size: 14px;
}

.popup p {

  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #716d6d;
}

.popup-form button.send {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  background-color: #db7d3a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}


.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #796454;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Mobile header*/

.header {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  
}

.mobmenu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}



.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 2.5px !important;
}

.hamburger-wrapper, .icons img {
  border-right: 1px solid #686464;
}

.hamburger {
  padding: 10px !important;

}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 32px !important;
}
  

  /*Mmenu styles*/
.mm-navbar {
  background-color: #dfddd8 !important;
  padding: 15px 0;

}

.mm-navbar span {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.mm-panel {
  background-color: #eceae6 !important;
}


.mm-listitem {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  color: #6a5346 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7e7e7e !important;

}

.mm-listitem:after {
  display: none !important;
}



.mm-wrapper_opening .mm-menu_offcanvas.mm-menu_opened~.mm-slideout {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}




@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .stucco-gal-info p {
    font-size: 15px !important;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info {
    padding: 40px 80px;
    text-align: left;
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
}




@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .stucco-gal-info {
    padding: 40px 60px;
    text-align: left;
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }

  .stucco-gal-info h3 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info p {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  a.gal-btn {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1268px) {
    .stucco-gal-info {
      padding: 40px 50px;
      text-align: left;
      transform: translateX(-10%);
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    

  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }

  .content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 55px;
  }

  .header h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .header h2.close {
    display: none;
  }


  .icons a {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
    
  
  .icons a.trolley {
    position: relative;
  }

  .notification {
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    right: 0;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #db7d3a;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .icons img {
    height: 17px;
    padding:  20px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  

  .icons img.loupe {
    border-left: 1px solid #686464;
  }

  .icons img.phone {
    border-right: none;
  }

  .icons img:nth-child(5){
    content: '0';
    border-radius: 100%;
  }

  .popup-wrapper {
    margin: 0 50px;
  }

  .main-section .owl-dots {
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }

  .info {
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 50px;
  }
  

  .stucco-gal-info {
    padding: 40px 80px;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1078px) {
  .stucco-gal-info {
    padding: 40px 70px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .info-text {
    padding: 20px;
  }


  .info-text h2 {
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .info-text p {
        font-size: 20px;
    }


 .container  {
   height: 500px;
 }

 .container img {
    height: 500px;
   width: 100vw;
 }

 
  .stucco-gal-info {
    padding: 40px 0;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }

  a.gal-btn {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .popup-img {
        display:none;
    }


  .info-text {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  
  .gallery-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
  }

 
  .stucco-gal .owl-dot.active {
    background-color: #f67e31;
  }


  .stucco-gal {
     width: 100% !important;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info {
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  .stucco-gal-info h3 {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }

  a.gal-btn {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 50px
  }

  .stucco-gal .owl-dots {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .info-text {
    padding: 15px;
  }

  .info-text h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .info-text p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .info-text h2, .info-text p {
    line-height: 1.5;
  }

  .info-button {
    padding: 10px
  }
}
    

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .icons img {
    height: 14px;
    padding:  25px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .header h2{
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .notification {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 515px) {
    .info-text {
      padding: 10px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .info-text h2 {
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .info-text p {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .info-button {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    
     .title span {
      font-size: 18px;
     }

     .title:before, .title:after {
        width: 70px;
      }
        
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .popup-form {
    padding: 40px !important;
  }

 
    .popup-close {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

  .info {
    padding: 0;
    left: 15px;
  }

  

  .hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {
    
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 2.5px !important;
  }


  .hamburger-box {
    width: 22px !important;
  }

  .header h2 {
    margin-left: 3px;
  }


    .icons img {
      height: 12px;
      padding:  22px 10px;
     }
     
     .notification {
      top: -30px;
      left: 0;
     } 
      
     .arrow{
      font-size: 20px !important;
       margin-left: 20px;
     }

     .main-section .owl-dots {
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 15px;
     }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 376px) {
  .icons img {
    height: 12px;
    padding:  22px 5px;
   }
   
   .title span {
      font-size: 16px;
   } 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clear.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adaptive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7dca09e227fdfe16908cebb4244589e4?family=Georgia" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/04219e2f2010127aaa13bb87e6dc50ec?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/5c803199923a6ed48112bebbb486b3e0?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/041a069e9ea3324a0b0c767aef875f17?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/629a55a7e793da068dc580d184cc0e31?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/mmenu.js"></script>
    <title>Сияние - Декор центр</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my-page">
            <div class="popup">

                <div class="popup-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="popup-img">

                        <img src="img/popup_img.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="popup-form">
                        <button class="popup-close">&times;</button>
                        <h3>обратная связь</h3>
                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="send(event, 'mail.php')">
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>E-mail <sup>*</sup></p>
                            <input type="email" name="user_email" required>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>Телефон <sup>*</sup></p>
                                <input type="tel" name="user_phone" required>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <p>Сообщение</p>
                                <textarea name="user_comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            
                             <button class="send" type="submit">Отправить</button>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
                <div class="sidebar">
                    
                        <div class="top-content">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <h1>сияние</h1>
                                    <span>декор центр</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                                <div class="desc">
                                    <p>Интернет-магазин отделочных материалов и дизайна</p>
                                </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu">

                            <div class="menu-main">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="menu-sub">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="contact">
                            <a href="tel:+78005118909" class="phone">+7 (4822) 648-080</a>
                            <a href="#" class="request">Заказать звонок</a>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="header">
                    <div class="mobmenu">
                        <a class="hamburger-wrapper" href="#mmenu">
                            <div class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze">
                              <div class="hamburger-box">
                                <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        
                        <a href="#"><h2>сияние</h2></a>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="icons">
                        <a href="#"><img class="loupe" src="img/icons/loupe.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/scale.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/heart.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/icons/user.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a class="trolley" href="#"><div class="notification">0</div><img src="img/icons/trolley.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="#"><img class="phone" src="img/icons/phone.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                        
                    <div class="main-section">
                        <div class="gallery">
                            <div class="owl-carousel">
                                <div class="container"><img src="img/bg-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="container"><img src="img/bg-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="container"><img src="img/bg-3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                <div class="container"><img src="img/bg-4.jpg" alt=""></div>
                            </div>
                                                
                        </div>

                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="info-text">
                                    <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
                                    <p>от лучших производителей</p>
                                </div>
                                <button class="info-button">Подробнее <span class="
                                            arrow">&rarr;</span> </button>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="stucco-section">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="title">
                                    <span>разделы каталога</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gallery-wrapper">
                                    <div class="gallery stucco-gal">
                                        <div class="owl-carousel">
                                            <div class="img">
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/bg-1.jpg);" class="pbg"></div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="img">
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/bg-2.jpg);" class="pbg"></div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="img">
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/bg-3.jpg);" class="pbg"></div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="img">
                                                <div style="background-image: url(img/bg-4.jpg);" class="pbg"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="stucco-gal-info">
                                        
                                        <h3>декоративная<br>лепнина</h3>
                                        <p>Идеальное решение для оформления элегантных интерьеров с минимальными...</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="gal-btn">Перейти в раздел</a>
                                    </div>  

                                </div>
                                


                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                </div>

    
            
    <nav id="mmenu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">каталог</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">столы</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">стулья</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">кровти</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">новости и акции</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">новость</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">акция</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">наши услуги</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">услуга 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">услуга 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">портфолио</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">фото</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
            <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
            
        </ul>
    </nav>          
</body>

    
<script>
// Отправка данных на сервер
function send(event, php){
console.log("Отправка запроса");
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', php, true);
req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
    json = JSON.parse(this.response); 
        console.log(json);
        
        // ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕМ ДЕЙСТВИЯ В СЛУЧАЕ УСПЕХА ИЛИ НЕУДАЧИ
        if (json.result == "success") {
            // Если сообщение отправлено
            alert("Сообщение отправлено");
        } else {
            // Если произошла ошибка
            alert("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }
    // Если не удалось связаться с php файлом
    } else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

// Если не удалось отправить запрос. Стоит блок на хостинге
req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}
</script>
 
            
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

странное совпадение, но сам недавно работал с этой библиотекой и такое же поведение было. решилось тем, что сначала дожидался загрузки изображений (через событие `onload`) а только потом запускал инициализацию слайдера библиотеки.

если точнее, то эта библиотека при инициализации вычисляет и задает своим блокам фиксированые размеры ширины, отталкиваясь от размеров изображений.
обратите внимание на размеры блоков `owl-item` и на их инлайн стили, которые задает библиотека. они неправильно вычисляются, по-этому у вас и такой баг.

Comment: а можно поподробнее?

Comment: @Tempest, отредактировал ответ.

Comment: @Tempest, покажите `js` код, где вы инициализируете слайдер

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wnqmhx3b/